# What does the delegate near @implementation do?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

in some code I saw something like this:

```
 @implementation SomeClass (SomeDelegate)
```

What does the `SomeDelegate`do in that context?

Cheers

Comment: This mean [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html). But I don' know what is the reason to call it `SomeDelegate`. Strange name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html). Given that it's call "SomeDelegate", I suspect that someone was just breaking up the code in their implementation file to group all the delegate methods together. Some people use multiple `@implementation` blocks to do that. This is the original use of categories. More often today, categories are used to extend existing classes. See the above link for more information.

Comment: I suspect 'SomeClass' and 'SomeDelegate' are just the OP rewriting it for the question (replacing the real classes etc)

Comment: You're right.
I didnt want to confuse anyone with the real classes.
How funny I did with these ones...

Comment: I had assumed that the "Some" was a stand-in. I only meant that if it ends in "Delegate" than it is probably a collection of delegate implementation methods rather than intended to extend the functionality of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It is a category, used to extend the functionality of existing classes. Check out my article on the subject which also contains a collection of really useful categories.

[Categories explanation and useful code...find it here.](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/)